# Not able to properly debug. Twilio Voice Bi-Directional Stream Logs?

Tags: debugging, logging, stream, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

We are having a hard time trying to get data on `timestamps` and `delays` on each point of:

1. User making a call to Twilio Number,
2. Invoking of the TWiML URL,
3. Sending and Receiving of Bi-Directional Stream data,
4. Sending data back to user.

Now, Twilio does provide logs on 2nd point as serverless API logs and top level events inside it. But there are no further information apart from that.

Is there a way to get this or is there something inside Twilio already to achieve this?

I have tried going through their docs and their youtube Signal videos. But I am not able to find a direct or in-direct way to achieve this.

Comment: You can include parameters in webhook endpoints such as a unique identifier. Your webhook handler can then use the unique identifier to compare when you originated the request and when Twilio responded. You will ultimately need to mix and match generating the timestamps yourself and storing them then comparing to the timestampts Twilio provides in webhooks. There is also the System Metrics Status Page if that is good enough: https://status.twilio.com/#system_metrics

Comment: Ok, thank you, do you know if twilio is working on making more indepth and accessible logs for their pipelines?

Comment: especially streaming logs @jassent

Comment: Between the logs and webhooks, the data for Voicecalls and Conference Calls is extremely detailed. Further, there is Voice Insights (https://www.twilio.com/en-us/voice/insights) and even the actual SIP PCAP files for the SIP transactions. The challenge is to store and bring together the various data points. For example, Twilio does not provide an "abandon" statistics - you will have to calculate that using the other available data (calls answered divided by calls offered).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio makes available [Custom Parameters to Share Information Between Your Applications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/how-share-information-between-your-applications).

For example, if you append a URL query parameter to a Twilio REST API request, Twilio will return that parameter in the response.

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxx/Calls.json 
--data-urlencode "Url=https://website.com/instructions" 
--data-urlencode "To=sip:bob@example.com?displayName=Alice&customerID=375d1d60-083b-404d&selectedProductID=87144192-73e2-45a6" 
--data-urlencode "From=+15017122661" 
-u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token
```

In the above example, when your Twiml endpoint https://website.com/instructions is called by Twilio, these parameters will also be included:

> displayName=Alice
>
> customerID=375d1d60-083b-404d
>
> selectedProductID=87144192-73e2-45a6

This will allow your application and Twilio to stay in sync.

For your question about Timestamps, you could pass a parameter such as "OriginatedTimestamp=2023-10-22T10:12:07.5980142Z"

Then when you receive a response, Twilio will include its own Timestamp and you can compare your OriginatedTimestamp with the Twimlio Timestamp parameter. This page lists all the [properties for a Call resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#call-properties).

If you haven't set it up already, Ngrok makes it very easy to view the properties returned by Twilio - Twilio explains this in a blog post about using [Ngrok in 2022](https://www.twilio.com/blog/using-ngrok-2022). A tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) will allow you to view your outgoing requests to Twilio while [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) will allow you to view the corresponding replies from Twilio.

Comment: Hey @jassent, thanks for the quick response. Although I was also looking for timestamps of when twilio sending the stream chunks, apart from when we receive them too.
But I was able to resolve the issue I was facing that I wanted to debug. It was due to wrong usage of some additional services.
Looking into Fiddler, I think that might help too.